# How to use tail -f with grep to show surrounding lines

Tags: grep, tail

I would like to see the output in a *logfile* greped by only one domain but also the following **two lines**.

Example:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log |grep mydomain.de
```

this shows all lines, that contain *"mydomain.de"* but the important information is in the line below the line, where the domain is included

Answer (score 37, accepted):

grep has extra options to define how many lines before and after the result:

- `-A` (after)
- `-B` (before)
- `-C` (context [before + after])

So in your case you need `-A`:

```
YOUR_COMMAND |grep -A NUMBER YOURDOMAIN
```

the above command prints `NUMBER` of lines after `YOURDOMAIN` in file.

Comment: Please note, however, that this is a GNU extension. If you're on Linux, your `grep` definitely has this option. If you're not, you better check.

Answer (score 10):

Try passing number of context lines to grep.

```
| grep -C 5
```

will print 5 lines before and after the match.